# Notation for a set of quantiles

Tags: statistics, notation, percentile, quantile

Is there a formal notation for a set of quantiles of for instance *x*, a numerical array?  This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2467225/77811) suggests the notation for percentile is P<sub>i</sub> (though what to do if you already have a variable P is unclear - I presume to use Q).  But how to represent a set?  Strictly speaking can it be a *set* if two quantiles share the same value?  I'm unclear if/how the notation for [an array](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/361530/77811) would apply here. A steer would be much appreciated.

I do note [this from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile):

[image]

But this seems aimed at identifying the "k-th" quantile.

Comment: You may want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic. You could use $X_{(\lfloor np \rfloor)}$

Comment: Instead of a set you could regard the quantiles as a sequence $Q_1,Q_2,\dots,Q_{n-1}$ since they can contain repeat elements. As for as notation either "$Q_i$, $0<i<n$" or "$(Q_i)_{i=1}^{n-1}$" may work.

Comment: Could you please expand on why you need the set of values that match a certain quantile?

Comment: @typewriter It's for an academic paper. Consider any made-up example array e.g. `x = P ⋅ log r / exp(q) (1)` I'd like to declare the set of quantiles/percentiles of the distribution of `x` in a formal way, whatever is most appropriate.

Comment: @M.Nestor this looks promising, thanks.