# What is the notation for the mean of $y$ in the $i$-th quantile of $x$?

Tags: notation, means, quantile

I would like to add the appropriate mathematical notation to use in a figure.

I have two original quantitative variables, $y$ and $x$, named “long variable name $y$” and “long variable name $x$”.

I have split the data across 100 quantiles of x, calculated the means of $y$ and the means of $x$ in each $i$-th quantile of $x$, and represented them as points in the Cartesian plane.

My questions are:

Q1. What is the appropriate name or notation for the $y$-axis, i.e. the mean of $y$ across the $i$-th quantile of $x$?

Q2. What is the appropriate notation for the $x$-axis, i.e. the mean of $x$ across the $i$-th quantile of $x$?

I have seen in [Notation for a set of quantiles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743060/notation-for-a-set-of-quantiles) suggestions for $(Q_i)^{n−1}_{i=1}$ or for
$X_{(\lceil np\rceil )}$ (with $n$ being the number of quantiles), as well as the [Wikipedia Order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) page. However, it is not evident to me if building from these options is appropriate.

In advance, I appreciate your time and your input on this question!